# Why sometimes in the U.S.A do they skip verbs?

Tags: american-english, slang, informal-language

Reading some lyrics from American songs, I've noticed that sometimes they skip verbs. For example in *F.N.* by Lil Tjay he says "You a Man, I don't fear you" Isn't this wrong? I think it should be *you're a man*. Why do they do this? Also sometimes they use the verb to be in infinite for example *I be*, why do they do this?

Comment: The Wikipedia article on [African American Vernacular English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/African-American_Vernacular_English) explains these grammatical variants in great detail.  However, as a learner, you should not be trying to imitate AAVE.

Comment: Not "In the USA" but "In songs"  (and more generally in situations that aren't formal prose).  The intention of all the grammatical manipulation is to create an impression, not to pass a grammar test at school.

Comment: Maybe you should talk to some Americans and listen to different styles of American music. The US is a nation of over 300 million people and your sample is a very small part of that whole.

Answer (score 9):

These are features of the dialect the rapper speaks, [African American Vernacular English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/African-American_Vernacular_English) (AAVE, aka African American Language: AAL):

> 1. **Deletion of verbal copula** (not as dirty as it sounds). This means that in some contexts, the word "is/are" can be left out. If you think this is "lazy grammar," speakers of Russian, Arabic, and Mandarin would like to have a word with you. example. *"he workin'."*
> 2. **A habitual aspect marker** (known as *habitual be*, or *invariant be*). Aspect refers to whether an action is completed or on-going. Habitual aspect means that a person regularly/often/usually does a thing, but does not give any indication of whether they are currently in the process of doing that thing. example: "*he be workin'*" (meaning: he is usually working.) — [Language Jones](https://www.languagejones.com/blog-1/2014/6/8/what-is-aave)

Using the [Corpus of Regional African American Language](http://lingtools.uoregon.edu/coraal/explorer/search.php) regex search you can find a lot more examples by searching for something like `\b(You|he|she|they|it) a [^,?!.]+`:

- > She a Golden State fan, my wife a Golden State fan
- > he a stand up guy, you know
- > she a single mother
- > You a high school teacher

Also `\b(You|he|she|they|it) be [^,?!.]+`:

- > It be everywhere
- > you be like
- > Or he be replacing it

I’m not sure the exact grammar behind this, but I know copula deletion can only be done where (in General American) *is/are* can be contracted (it’s non stressed).

Also note that these grammatical features are [not present in General American](https://www.antiracismdaily.com/archives/respect-aave-anti-racism-daily) or ["Standard" British](https://www.thoughtco.com/standard-british-english-1692136). Both features are said to be characteristic of AAVE specifically (and in my experience when you hear these features from non-AAVE speakers they’re mimicking AAVE), though it’s relevant to note:

- "[T]he zero copula is very rarely found in the speech of whites, even poor southern whites. Not all blacks use it either." — [An Introduction to Sociolinguistics](https://www.thoughtco.com/zero-copula-grammar-1692518)
- *Habitual be* can be found in other "regional varieties of English", (some black, but even some white) as noted by the [Yale Diversity Project](https://ygdp.yale.edu/phenomena/invariant-be#who-says-this)
- See also [The Creole Origins of African American Vernacular English:  Evidence from copula absence](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Erickford/papers/CreoleOriginsOfAAVE.html)